# ASP.NET 2.0 - ClickOnce - Processor Architecture Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickonce

Any way to change processor architecture from any CPU to x86 without existing installs of a clickonce application having to reinstall?

We attempted this and it changes the identity in the clickonce manifest file which then throws an error when the client tries to update. All indications are that the users must reinstall from everything I've read. Most topics were from 2008-2009 so I wasn't sure if any new updates had been made to where ClickOnce can allow the target CPU to be changed without the manifest having problems.

Comment: What is forcing the change from "Any CPU" to "x86", 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had to change architecture of our ClickOnce deployment to x86 thanks to a 3rd party control not handling 64 bit.  We're using .NET 4.0 and the same is still true.  We even went so far as to resign the certificate, but I don't know if that was a requirement.